# Java 8 has broken my application that uses PKCS12

Tags: java, pkcs#12

In 2007 I wrote a tiny java application that would digitally sign several different PDF documents (with image of my signature).  I has been working great until I upgraded to Java 8.

I am now getting errors:

```
IOException: Unable to read private key from keystore
e: java.io.IOException: unsupported PKCS12 secret value type 48
```

I seems now that Java 8 PKCS12 cannot store secret key entries.  This is a critical application for me. I use it hundreds of times a day.

How can I work around this issue?

Here is an abridged version of the critical code:

```
String appPath =  SignPDF.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();

String keytype  =  "pkcs12";
String keyfile  =  appPath + "DanVokt.pfx";
String keyimage =  appPath + "DanVokt.png";
String keypass  =  "xxxxxxxxx";

KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(keytype);
ks.load(new FileInputStream(keyfile), keypass.toCharArray());
String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();
PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, keypass.toCharArray());
Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(ifile);
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(ofile);

PdfStamper stp = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, fout, '\0');
PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stp.getSignatureAppearance();
sap.setCrypto(key, chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.SELF_SIGNED);

// allow only printing
stp.setEncryption(null, keypass.getBytes(), PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING,
                  PdfWriter.STANDARD_ENCRYPTION_128);
stp.close();
```

Here is a stack tace:

```
$ signpdf "Timelog*" 1
Processing File: "Timelog - Current Week.pdf" 1
IOException: Unable to read private key from keystore
java.io.IOException: unsupported PKCS12 secret value type 48
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.loadSafeContents(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2197)
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2025)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at SignPDF.main(SignPDF.java:61)
```

Here is the version and build:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Attempt to use keytool to view PKCS12 (.pfx) file:

```
$ keytool -list -keystore DanVokt.pfx -storepass XXXXXXXX -storetype PKCS12 -v
keytool error: java.io.IOException: unsupported PKCS12 secret value type 48
java.io.IOException: unsupported PKCS12 secret value type 48
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.loadSafeContents(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2197)
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2025)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:795)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:343)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:336)
```

Comment: Please include the complete stacktraces for the exception.  It will help us to figure out what is going on.  Also, please provide the Java version / build number for the JRE you are using to run the code.

Comment: While looking for a fix you can have an older version of Java installed for this only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RESOLVED]

I created a java keystore (JKS) file:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore danv_keystore.jks -alias danv
```

Of course this created a new private key and new certificate but that is currently not an issue since it is self-signed.  I am a bit confused on how to use my own private key and certificate.  Any examples?

I then simply changed the keytype and keyfile:

```
//        String keytype  =  "pkcs12";
        String keytype  =  "JKS";
//        String keyfile  =  appPath + "DanVokt.pfx";
        String keyfile  =  appPath + "danv_keystore.jks";
```

And voila! It is now working again.

I compiled it under J8 and J7 and it works in both environments.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit of digging.  The change appears to have happened as part of some Keystore API enhancements.  (They were [committed](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/rev/1da93663f8f3) in January 2013)

The specific test is this:

```
        } else if (bagId.equals((Object)SecretBag_OID)) {
            DerInputStream ss = new DerInputStream(bagValue.toByteArray());
            DerValue[] secretValues = ss.getSequence(2);
            ObjectIdentifier secretId = secretValues[0].getOID();
            if (!secretValues[1].isContextSpecific((byte)0)) {
                throw new IOException(
                    "unsupported PKCS12 secret value type "
                                    + secretValues[1].tag);
            }
```

where `!(isContextSpecific()` is checking the "tag" of the DERvalue to make sure that it doesn't have the CONTEXT bit set.  This test is failing.

It would seem that the work-around would be to store these secret keys as DER values with a tag type that doesn't have bit `0x80` set.

See also:

- PKCS12KeyStore.java - https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/pkcs12/PKCS12KeyStore.java
- DERValue.java - https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/util/DerValue.java